# Ubuntu 15.10 slow boot

Tags: boot

My Ubuntu 15.10 is booting very slow. This is my `dmesg` output:

```
...
[   10.045029] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[   10.048193] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[   10.396115] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   10.396118] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   10.396122] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   10.411786] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   10.411792] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   10.411797] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   11.866507] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[   11.866536] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
[   94.430576] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: SK
[   94.430579] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[   94.430580] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   94.430582] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   94.430583] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   94.430584] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   94.430586] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[   94.430587] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
```

I think that problem is somewhere about 94 second, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a few bugs in linux kernel relating to this:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95461